# How to remove the extra line?

Tags: spacing, line-breaking

I use this command to show the headword in dictionary.

```
\newcommand{\entry}[2]{\hangpara{2em}{1}\textsf{\textbf{#1}}\ #2 \markboth{#1}{#1}\par}\nopagebreak[4]
```

When the headword is exactly as long as the line, there appears an extra line below the headword. What can I do with it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) It's not necessary to sign your questions (as there is already a box with your username below it) or to begin them with a greeting.

Comment: If, by "headword" you mean the entire contents printed by `\entry` (in other words, both arguments `#1` and `#2`), does removing the space between `#2` and `\markboth` correct the behaviour?

Comment: It is always best to compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that exactly illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Yes, removing the space between `#2` and `\markboth` corrected the behaviour. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The spurious space between `#2` and `\markboth` might cause an unexpected line break at the end of typesetting `#2` if `#2` finishes close to the line margin. As such removing it should fix your "extra line" problem.